# Flag module views integration

Tags: views, entities, 6, flags

Following an excellent suggestion, I added the [Flag](https://www.drupal.org/project/flag) module to a website in order to allow users to store their favorite stories in a dedicated page. This seems to be working really nicely, but how do I now add the option to flag content as a field in a view?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you want to display a list of content a user has flagged - You want build your view as you would any other. Then you add a relationship to the view for the flag you wish to display.

If you wish to allow your user to simply add a flag directly from the view results, you would add a field to the view of the type "Flags: Flag Link". This will add the add/remove flag link to each result in your view.

Comment: this is right, adding the relationship for the flag is the key to integrating the module with you views

Comment: Thank you! I'm trying to add a flag link but I'm not seeing this option in Views...?

Comment: You have to add a relationship and select "flag" there first; then flag will become available as an option in fields.