# Managing Abusive/Report User

Tags: views, users, flags

I have setup flags so a user can report another user as abusive/offensive. I need a way to manage to flags. I would like to be able the view all the users that have been flagged and and remove the flags. I have tried to do this with views but I could not find a way to remove the flag.

Answer (score 0):

Look at the answer in this question: [Flag module views integration](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/11798/flag-module-views-integration)

It seems to be possible with relationships, though I would guess that this depends a little on your flag configuration.

Comment: I figured out how to do but I had the set the flag to global and changed the permissions so users can't unflag and admin can flag and unflag. If it's not set to global the admin can't remove someone else's flag.